# Issue logging in on external server

Tags: logging, log

For some reason when users try to log on to our server from external computers they are getting the access denied screen, and it tells them they do not have access, when they indeed do have access to the page.

I even have tested logging on to the page on an internal computer with the account and I can get on fine, I have also tested some of them using external computers and it has worked for me. I am beginning to rule out user error as it has happened to many users.

Any ideas why these users cannot access a page using our domain on an external computer? This is on SharePoint 2013, and we didn't have any issues like this before we migrated from 2010 but now they are happening very often.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Must users have a certain level of permissions in the list of the page they are trying to reach? (Above limited Access)

Comment: Yes, if they dont have at least Read permission to your landing page, they will get access denied.

Comment: So for them to have access to the page they also need read access to the list? And would they also need it to the site that the list is on, and the top level sites?

Comment: Yes, they need read access to all that and any assets, like images, the style library, etc.

Comment: I just find this issue odd, because we never had problems like this in 2010, did they make changes in 2010 to the way permissions work?

Comment: It's possible the migration altered permissions if you went to a different auth, like nltm to claims

Comment: Do you know if there is a way for me to check that? and if switching could fix some of there problems? (Thank you for your help and continued support)

Comment: You can use the check permissions option in the site permissions, to see their access level, that the same option is available at the list and library level.

Comment: what is your authentication method and what site template is being used?